# Анимация перемещения image в svg

Tags: svg, svg-animation

```html
<svg id="example2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image width="100" height="100" x="150" y="10" xlink:href="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/33ff99/555555?text=logo1" />
    <image id="orange-circle" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" xlink:href="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/33ff99/555555?text=logo2" />
    <!-- <circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange" /> -->
    <animate 
    xlink:href="#orange-circle" 
    attributeName="cx" 
    from="50" to="450" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
</svg>
```

У меня есть код который вставляет ***2*** картинки и код анимации, который должен переместить картинку вправо.

Анимация работает с ***`circle`*** но не работает с ***`image`***.

Что я делаю не правильно?

Comment: у `image` атрибут `х` а не `сх`

Comment: А если нужно будет и по x и по у перемещать, это для каждого вектора отдельная анимация?

Comment: это можно сделать даже без smil - просто на keyframes

Comment: @test есть еще атрибут transform

Answer (score 2):

Справочная информация

Старайтесь не задавать `id` через дефис между словами `#orange-circle` В командах анимации Firefox воспринимает это, как вычитание и анимация не работает. Это давно известный баг FF

Команды анимации можно писать, как вне тела кода, анимамированного объекта, так и внутри него. Надежнее и нагляднее последний способ написания анимации внутри объекта

```
<image .....>
<animate .... />
</image>
```

Обратите внимание на первую строчку, - тег `image` не закрыт и обязательно закрывающий тег `</image>` после окончания команды анимации.

### Перемещения картинки.

Можно изменять параметр `x`, но это сильно нагружает видеокарту, так идет постоянный пересчет редеринга при перемещении на каждый пиксель.
Как указал в комментариях @Stranger in the Q лучше использовать `transform="translate(x,y)"`

**Перемещение по X**
Изменяем только координату `x` в команде `translate`

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" 
  begin="0s" dur="4s" values="0,10;200,10;0,10" repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

```html
<svg id="example2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image width="100" height="100" x="150" y="10" xlink:href="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/33ff99/555555?text=logo1" />
    
 <image id="orange-circle" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" 
 xlink:href="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/33ff99/555555?text=logo2" >
     <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="0,10;200,10;0,10" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 </image>  

  <circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange"> 
    <animate 
    attributeName="cx" 
    from="50" to="450" dur="2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </circle>
</svg>
```

**Перемещение по обоим координатам сразу**

Изменяем  обе координаты `x, y` в команде translate

```html
<svg id="example2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image width="100" height="100" x="150" y="10" xlink:href="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/33ff99/555555?text=logo1" />
    
 <image id="orange-circle" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" 
 xlink:href="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/33ff99/555555?text=logo2" >
     <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="0,10;200,10;200,100;10,100;0,10" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
 </image>  

  <circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange"> 
    <animate 
    attributeName="cx" 
    from="50" to="450" dur="2s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" />
 </circle>
</svg>
```

**Перемещение группы объектов**

В примере ниже круг и одно из изображений оборачиваются в групповой тег `<g>` и анимация применяется в целом для группы

```html
<svg id="example2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image width="100" height="100" x="150" y="10" xlink:href="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/33ff99/555555?text=logo1" />
  
  <g>
 <image id="orange-circle" width="100" height="100" x="0" y="0" 
 xlink:href="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100/33ff99/555555?text=logo2" >
  </image>  
  <circle id="orange-circle" r="30" cx="50" cy="50" fill="orange"/> 
   <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="0s" dur="4s" values="0,10;200,10;200,100;10,100;0,10" repeatCount="indefinite" /> 
  </g>  
 
</svg>
```

Comment: @test Добавлен ответ.

Comment: @test у вас есть вопросы, что-то не понятно? Спрашивайте